# Prove that if $2^a$ is superperfect, then $2^{a+1} - 1$ is a Mersenne prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, perfect-numbers

Definition: Let $n \in \Bbb Z$ with $n>0$. Then $n$ is said to be superperfect if $σ(σ(n))=2n$. Where $σ$ is the sum of positive divisors arithmetic function.

I am trying to solve a proof that asks: Prove that if $2^a$ is superperfect, then $2^{a+1} - 1$ is a Mersenne prime.

So far, this is what I got:

Assume $2^a$ is superperfect. Then, $σ(σ(2^a)) = 2(2^a) = 2^{a+1}$. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I don't understand how I could show $2^{a+1} - 1$ is a Mersenne prime from what I have so far. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly! I am confused. So following your suggestions, I got σ(2^a) = 2^(a+1) - 1 = 2^a * 2 - 1. I don't know how to proceed from there.

Comment: $\sigma(n) = \sum_{d | n} d = 1+n+ \sum_{d | n, 1 < d < n} d$. in other words : $n$ is prime $\Leftrightarrow$ $\sigma(n) = ?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key was stated in comments, you need do the substitution that you've computed as $$\sigma(2^a)=2^{a+1}-1$$ in your condition deduced from the assumption that $2^a$ is superperfect.
Then do a comparison between the result and the implication (that is a proposition) $$\sigma(N)=N+1\implies N\text{ is prime}.$$
Notice that you've deduced before $\sigma(N)=N+1$, where the substitution is saying to you what is your $N$. Then since you have $\sigma(N)=N+1$ for a $N$ you can conclude that $N$ is prime (that is, the only difficulty here is if you know how show for any $m$ that: *if* $\sigma(m)=m+1$ *then* $m$ *is prime*).